DBT Core- Snapshot: Parsing Error at path []: Snapshots must be configured with a ‘strategy’, ‘unique_key’, and ‘target_schema’
In dbt-core, I have created a folder under snapshots called salesforce. All my snapshot sqls are in this folder. Now I have a few common configs that I have added in dbt_project.yml given below:
snapshots:
  salesforce:
    +unique_key: id
    +target_schema: snapshots
    +invalidate_hard_deletes: True

And the remaining configs in my respective sqls in config:
{{
    config(
      strategy='timestamp',
      updated_at='SYSTEM_MODSTAMP',
    )
}}

However, when I run dbt snapshot command with this setup, I get the following error:
Parsing Error
at path : Snapshots must be configured with a ‘strategy’, ‘unique_key’, and ‘target_schema’.
When I dont create the salseforce folder under snapshot and add all my sqls directly under snapshot with following configuration it works.
snapshots:
   +unique_key: id
   +target_schema: snapshots
   +invalidate_hard_deletes: True

What am I missing?

You should provide your project name in between:
snapshots:
  project_name:
    salesforce:
      +unique_key: id
      +target_schema: snapshots
      +invalidate_hard_deletes: True


snapshots: — everything including packages
snapshots: project_name: — excluding packages
snapshots: project_name: subfolder: — only for a specific subfolder

The project name normally is on the top of your dbt_project.yml.
